# .htaccess and 500 server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm deploying a new website, which currently runs fine locally, but returns a 500 internal server error on live. I've ensured that all permissions are set to 755, but no cigar.

Here is the .htaccess file, but since I'm the front-end dev, I don't fully understand all the rules, so I can't determine if anything could be causing this error.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# BASE APACHE RULES
#
# When running in a subdirectory, you should uncomment and adjust the
# RewriteBase rule to point to your directory, eg. RewriteBase /directory/
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REMOVE TRAILING SLASHES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STATIC CACHING PROXY
#
# Enable these rules when using static html caching
# to bypass Statamic when a given URL has a cached copy.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f
# RewriteRule ^(.*) static/$1/index.html


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PROTECT SYSTEM DIRECTORIES
#
# Not necessary when running above webroot.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteRule ^site/(?!themes) - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^local - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^statamic - [F,L]


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ROUTE THROUGH INDEX.PHP
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# upload assets restriction
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
php_value memory_limit 30M
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Any help would be appreaciated!

Comment: Don't guess at your problem. Check your apache error log for the details and then you can fix it. If you don't know what to do, post error here and we'll try to help.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there's no /usr directory for me to check server logs. Also couldn't find any in /var.

Comment: They are somewhere on your server. Check you apache config file for the location. You **can't** troubleshoot withou it. Nobody is going to guess what's causing your 500 error. It could be dozens of things.

Comment: I understand. I'm trying to access the httpd.conf file to locate the logs, but it doesn't seem like we have root-level access. I'll come back if I can get the logs. Thanks.